# Is it possible to migrate programs from 32 bit Windows to a new 64 bit Windows machine (both Windows 7)?

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I've got a Windows 7 Pro 32 bit PC. Getting a new Windows 7 Home *64* bit.

Is there anything I can use to transfer my  *programs* (the ones that don't come in a 64 bit flavor)  to the new PC?
There is a related [question](https://superuser.com/questions/613582/upgrading-from-32-to-64-bit-windows-7-without-losing-program-installations-game?lq=1) that doesn't address the programs part.

Comment: 32bit applications installed on 64bit versions of Windows simply install in the Program Files (x86), although some applications may not be fully compatible.

Comment: That's a related question?!

Comment: Most applications use the registry the best way is to simply transfer the settings file for those programs and reinstall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since programs normally tend to litter files and settings all over the place unless they're portable, it's not always easy or even possible to transfer them from one 32-bit PC to another, forget 32 to 64-bit. There are third-party programs that claim to reliably transfer apps, but I would recommend that you simply reinstall. What you can do is export and/or back up any related settings/configuration files and the like (including from the registry), *if* possible, and import on your new PC after the apps are reinstalled.

Answer (score 2):

There are 3rd party tools which offers this:

http://ww2.laplink.com/pcmover/index.html

I tried it, but it doesn't really worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say off the top NO....mostly because installed programs have made some type of registry modifications.  Missing the registry modifications will make programs that have simply been copied not functional.  The detective work required can be significant.

Then there is the matter for going from a "Professional" version to a "Home" version.  There could be other potholes waiting for you to explode them.  The old programs could use capabilities not present on the Home version.

So my suggestion to you is simply go back to the original ISO/DVD/* install media and re-install your stash to the new Home system from scratch.  It could save you a lot of time in debugging problems, and I'm sure you don't want to devote your life to a puzzle like this can produce.

Answer (score 1):

It seems possible as shown in the following clip:

http://www.pickmeapp.com/content/workaround-adobe-photoshop-cs4#comment-42

Photoshop CS4 was transfered from a 32-bit Windows XP system to a 64-bit Windows 7 install.

So it means that the PickMeApp tool may correctly set up the default installation path of 64 bit replacing a 32 bit installation path. Also, it may correctly register COM and assemblies as 64-bit. It probably makes other tweaks as well.

Comment: Link only answers die quickly. Summarize what you find in that video, then paste a link as attribution