# Backing up software with its licenses

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, 64-bit, license

I have a PC which is mostly used for photo and video editing. This PC was starting to get slow and I decided I had to install some more RAM memory in it (6GB in total now).

After doing that, I noticed the PC was only running Windows 7 32bit. (oops)

The PC is full of licensed software, where I basically don't have the packages from anymore, where the serials were located.

[I've read](https://superuser.com/q/613582/365878), when you are upgrading your Windows 7 32bit PC to an x64 architecture, it's always a clean install.

Is there any way to upgrade your Windows 7 32bit computer to an Windows 7 64bit computer and re-install the data which was on the old PC?.

Comment: I think this has to be done on a case by case basis. Each program has its own way to store a license.

Comment: @Malcolm Alright, so you can't make a image of the computer's installed software, with its settings?

Comment: You can try that, but if an app, for example, stores this stuff in the registry, this may not work as the location can be different for the x64 system.

Comment: @Malcolm So I have to do this all seperatly for each application? No software reccomandations? :P

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that the question needs a list of software, then someone will probably be able to leave an answer on backing up the licenses.